# Генерация MPEG-DASH VOD Манифеста с аудио и видео из одиночного .webm файла

Tags: ffmpeg, libvpx, libopus, .webm

Нужно ли разбивать файл на два потока аудио(libopus) и видео(libvpx) в виде .webm файлов или существует возможность сгенерировать  манифест с аудио и видео из одного .webm файла?

Comment: Как написано в спецификации webm - упаковка метаданных базируется на matroska, а это в свою очередь поддерживается ffmpeg (по заявлению, сам не пробывал) в полной мере. Потому должно работать без разбивки потоков. Это только направление, "куда копать" :)

Comment: ffmpeg + nginx-rtmp должны решить проблему

Comment: gbg, кто сказал, что это вообще задача требует решения в веб? ИМХО наличие расширения webm еще не говорит, что прикладное решение именно в данной области....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дмитрий, приветствую :-)
Да, нужно.
Нужно иметь отдельный файл на каждый поток.

> For streaming WebM files using DASH, the video and audio files have to be non-muxed and non-chunked (i.e.) each video stream goes into it’s own file and each audio stream goes into it’s own file. For more information on what this means see this link.

Источник: 
[Instructions to playback Adaptive WebM using DASH](http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-adaptive-webm-using-dash)